# How To Get Width Of Canvas Placed On Responsive HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, width

My HTML File

```
<div id="canvas">
<canvas id="myCanvas">
</div>
```

My CSS FIle

```
#canvas
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#myCanvas
{
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
}
```

Using Javascript I Am Drawing An Image On Canvas (Redraw After 1 Second). This Page Is Responsive. So Canvas Width Changes As Browser Width Change. In ImageDraw Function I Am Trying To Get Width Of Canvas

```
c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");

canvaswidth = c.width;
```

But Even After Changing Width Of Browser I Am Getting Canvas Width As 300. What Is The Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual dimensions of the HTMLCanvasElement are defined by its "width" and "height" properties, which are *different* from the CSS style-declaration ! Setting the CSS attributes different to those of the canvas' width and height will result in scaling the canvas by the browser, as if you were zooming content.

To match your expectancy what you'd want is to explicitly set the width and height of the canvas to match the percentages you'd expect from the CSS declartions, i.e. : measure the dimensions in pixels of the canvas' parent container (let's assume 320px width in this example), multiply it by the percentage of choice (let's say 90% which is 320 * .9 == 288 pixels) and set it onto the canvas' width property, do the same for the height et voila.

**Note:** this has implications for your draw-methods, depending on how you're drawing the content onto the canvas (i.e. when using absolute values for coordinates and dimensions) it might actually be more feasible to just have it scaled by CSS !

Comment: I Draw Image, Based On Width Of Canvas And Canvas Width Changes When Browser Width Change So How To Achieve That ?

Comment: In that case store the calculation for the canvas width in a variable and use those and all should be fine, but I'm wondering : is it actually a problem in your responsive app with the CSS scaling ? (i.e. does the image look good and does it behave it well across all resolutions and is the question more related as to WHY the dimension of the canvas is always "300") ?

Comment: Canvas Is Responsive But Problem Is Image And Letters Are Draws As Per 300Width Of Canvas N Look Blurred When I Maximize Browser. So I Want In Next Draw Canvas Width Be Equal To Browser Width But I Am Getting 300 Everytime As A Browser Width

Comment: In that case please review my original answer as to why this occurs and how to overcome this.

Comment: Suppose My Screen Resolution : 1366*766 And I Resize Browser. Now How To Get % (ie 90% or 80%) Of Browser Resize So I Can Calculate Pixels

Comment: Read up (it's on this site) how to get a cross browser-proof way to get the current window dimensions from the browser, but for brevity here's a quick example:

document.documentElement.clientWidth * .90;

This would return 90% of the available browser width in pixels. (for IE you can use window.innerWidth instead of querying the documentElement). Also note that on mobile devices you might need window.orientation to determine whether the device is held in portrait or landscape orientation (and inverse the "width" and the "height" properties).